# Synology Drive Client integration

Tags: wingpanel, pantheon-files, icons

Is there a way to correctly integrate synology drive client in Eos?
I can install .deb package from synology website, but unfortunately without folder/files status overlays and app indicator on system tray, working with the client it’s really difficult. Is there any plug-in availbale for the integration?

Answer (score 0):

If the client were to support `libcloudproviders` then Files in elementary 6.0 should support it.

Comment: Seems that nautilus is already supporting it. For anyone interested in making this work in juno, i managed to make synology drive work by installing nautilus from the app center and by following this guide to re-enable applications on wingpanel: https://www.google.it/amp/s/www.reallinuxuser.com/how-to-show-app-indicators-on-the-system-tray-in-elementary-os/amp/